# How can I reassign my gem skills?

Tags: path-of-exile

As a Marauder, I have picked up a few skills through quests that are weapon dependent.  Unfortunately, some of them require mutually exclusive weapons (e.g. Glacial Hammer requires blunt weapons and Cleave requires edged weapons).

This means that every time I upgrade to a new weapon, if the weapon type changes, I may wind up with skills that I can't use.

At this point, I have more skills than actually fit in the automatically assigned keys (mouse scroll button, mouse right button, q, w, e, r t).  I'd like to be able to remove the skills that aren't currently enabled (i.e. cleave when I'm using a mace), while still leaving them socketed so they'll continue to level up.

I'd also like to be able to reassign the keys to put them on more convenient hotkeys, yet I have a hard time doing this (I've had to resort to a trial-and-error process of swapping in and out unwanted skills to prevent other skills from automatically assigning to the "wrong" spot).

Is there a way to simply assign skills to specific hotkeys?

Comment: Why would you use cleave on marauder? Cleave is STR-DEX skill, meaning duelist should use it. Sooner or later you wont be able to level it up anymore due to dex requirement being too high, unless you increase DEX on Marauder which i wouldn't suggest of doing. There are a lot better AoE skills for Marauder anyway, like Sweep and Ground Slam, and you can use both with 2H Maces which is what I'm doing.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ I've decided to build around 1 hand, which rules Sweep out, I believe. Cleave was one of my very first quest rewards, and the only AOE I have aside from Molten Armor, which is about as ineffective an AOE as you can possibly have. When I switched to the nice rare mace I found, I felt gimped because I had almost no AOE capability. In all honesty, I didn't even realize Cleave had a dex requirement (it doesn't at the first few levels), and they seem low enough that I'm not certain if it will even be an issue.

Comment: `Cleave is STR-DEX skill, meaning duelist should use it.`  The PoE skills system is open enough precisely to avoid that kind of build constraint.  That's exactly why it's a great hns, imo :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game will automatically assign new skills to any empty slots in your hotkey menu. However, if you click on any of the skill slots in the bottom right, you can assign/unassign whichever attack/skill you want.